# Angular - one 'big' Module or for each feature separated Module?

Tags: angular, structure, project-management, setup-project, angular-module

I've just created my Angular 5 project, which contains like 20-30 components organized in folders like:

> productFolder
>
> -- product component
>
> articleFolder
>
> -- article components

So my question is should I create one big module which should import all of these components, or for each component there should be corresponding module for example:

> productFolder
>
> -- product component
>
> -- product module.ts
>
> articleFolder
>
> -- article components
>
> -- article module.ts

and so on...

So I am confused here, should I create module for each component and why?
Or there should be one big module which would import all of these components?

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should create separate module for each component which is advised by Angular developers.

**Why?**

- Keeps your code loosely coupled, which makes it easier to change.
- Keeps your code clean.
- Single Responsibility Principle and many more.

More such guidelines for angular you can find on https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Answer (score 0):

Definitely create a module for both, products and articles. Read about [Feature Modules](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules) in the official docs.

> A feature module is an organizational best practice, as opposed to a concept of the core Angular API. A feature module delivers a cohesive set of functionality focused on a specific application need such as a user workflow, routing, or forms. While you can do everything within the root module, feature modules help you partition the app into focused areas. A feature module collaborates with the root module and with other modules through the services it provides and the components, directives, and pipes that it shares.